# Enable TLS in soapui

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, soapui, tls1.2

```
     ERROR: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
        I tried changing vmoptions and test runner. sh with the below param but still the same error. 
        -Djava.security.egd=`file:///dev/urandom`
        -Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2
        -Dsoapui.https.ciphers='AES256-SHA256'
        I tried different combinations for cipher like 
        `AES256-SHA`,'AES256-SHA256','TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA'
```

Details ERROR:java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:878)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils$DriverProxy.connect(GroovyUtils.java:148)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.jdbc.JdbcUtils.initConnection(JdbcUtils.java:62)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.getDatabaseConnection(JdbcSubmit.java:190)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.prepare(JdbcSubmit.java:222)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.runQuery(JdbcSubmit.java:173)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.run(JdbcSubmit.java:147)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:874)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:174)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:555)
at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readNIOPacket(NIOPacket.java:403)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:127)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:340)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1600)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:591)
... 17 more*

Comment: Please provide full stack trace and snippets from TLS handshake debug. This can be SNI or many other problems.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To enable TLS in SoapUi to connect to the database:

1. Create jdbc like: 
   `jdbc:oracle:thin:user/passward@(description=(address=(protocol=tcps)(host=xyz)(port=portno))(connect_data=(sid=abc)))`
2. Edit test_runner:

   `JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%  -Doracle.net.wallet_location=file:/oravl01/oracle/12.2.0.1//client_wallet SoapUI_CLASSPATH="${SoapUI_CLASSPATH}:${ORACLE_PKI}:${OSDT_CERT}:${OSDT_CORE}"`